# Unable to copy multiple files via scp

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, scp

This command for connecting to my aws server **works well**:

```
ssh -i my_pem.pem ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

But this not:

```
$ scp -v -i my_pem.pem file1 file2 ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/folder1
```

**UPDATE1**:

```
$ ssh -v -i 123.pem ubuntu@xx-xx-xx-xx.xx-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xx-xx-xx-xx.xx-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [11.22.33.44] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file docs/toh_server.pem type -1
debug1: identity file docs/toh_server.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA xx:bb:cc:dd:ee:fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfds
debug1: Host 'xx-xx-xx-xx.xx-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/me123/.ssh/known_hosts:19
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: docs/toh_server.pem
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to xx-xx-xx-xx.xx-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com ([11.33.44.55]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_HK.UTF-8
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-48-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

 System information disabled due to load higher than 2.0

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud
```

Error:

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host ip-xx-xx-xx-xx, user ubuntu, command scp -v -d -t /home/ubuntu/folder1
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ip-xx-xx-xx-xx: Name or service not known
lost connection
```

What's the matter?

Comment: what does the -v stsnds for?, why not use the same dyntax, just -i

Comment: @datelligence, why don't you open the docs?

Comment: "Could not resolve hostname" does not look like problem with `scp` and more files, but with your network. What do you have in your `~/.ssh/config` file? Try to put more `-vvv` in the command line to see more logs. your hostname is getting lost somewhere on the way from `scp` to `ssh`

Comment: @Jakuje, well, why does "ssh" work?

Comment: @Jakuje, what should I have in ssh/config file?

Comment: cat: /home/me123/.ssh/config: No such file or directory But so far, and I've had this Ubuntu for many months, I've always used ssh without any error.

Comment: Sorry. This one `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. But it will probably not be related. Rather add the full verbose logs from boths `scp` and `ssh`. And make sure none of your files you are uploading does not have `@` in the name.

Comment: @Jakuje,  updated. no @ in the file names. what do you mean by "-v" for scp, I've already shown it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the difference

```
debug1: Connecting to xx-xx-xx-xx.xx-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [11.22.33.44] port 22.
```

and

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host ip-xx-xx-xx-xx, user ubuntu, command scp -v -d -t /home/ubuntu/folder1
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ip-xx-xx-xx-xx: Name or service not known
```

Your `scp` is connecting somewhere else and since you obfuscated the IPs/addresses I have no idea if that is intention or that the it really does.

The `scp` is parsing your files and probably found some `:` character in your file name (first guess about `@` was false) and parses that filename as `host:path`? Give it a try with only one of the files, post the real name of files.

Or rather use `sftp`. It does not care about the syntax on command line. Just `sftp your host` and then:

```
cd folder1
put my_file file2
```

Comment: **Your scp is connecting somewhere else and since you obfuscated the IPs/addresses** I think that's just a real IP address because in the command I use the name of the host